# Mongoose Schema & Refactoring

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**I. This Works:**

***//dbModuleSchema.js***

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function getDbModuleSchema() {
    var dbModuleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    roles : [rolesSchema] <--------------------------- from local variable
   };

    ///////////////////////////////////
    // local variable for roles schema 
    ///////////////////////////////////
    var rolesSchema = mongoose.Schema({ //<------------ local variable
        name : {type : String},
        description : {type: String}
    };
    return dbModuleSchema;
};

exports.getDbModuleSchema = getDbModuleSchema;
```

---

**II. This doesn't:**

***//dbModuleSchema.js***

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    securitySchema = require('./../security/securitySchema');

function getDbModuleSchema() {
    var dbModuleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    roles : [securitySchema.getRolesSchema] <-- from separate securitySchema module
   }
    return dbModuleSchema;
};

exports.getDbModuleSchema = getDbModuleSchema;
```

***//securitySchema.js***

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function getRolesSchema() { //<------ separate securitySchema module
    var rolesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name : {type : String},
        description : {type: String}
    };
    return rolesSchema;
};

exports.getRolesSchema = getRolesSchema;
```

---

**III. With this as my json:**

```
{
    "moduleStyleId" : "style-0",
    "name" : "My Dashboard",
    "roles" : [{"name" : "Employee", "description" : "Everyone"}]
},
```

**IV. The difference between I & II.**

In I, I declared the roles schema in the same module, In II, I refactored it out to it's own seperate module and called its function within the moduleSchema.

Am I not allowed to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Figured it out, the key is to pass the remote module to a variable first:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    securitySchema = require('../security/securitySchema');

function getDbModuleSchema() {
    var rolesSchema = securitySchema.getRolesSchema(); <--- pass remote schema to variable first
    var dbModuleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        roles : [rolesSchema],
       };
    return dbModuleSchema;
};

exports.getDbModuleSchema = getDbModuleSchema;
```

Thanks, guys, couldn't have done it w/o **"youse"**! ;)